# Programmatically sort Excel spreadsheets

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, ms-office, openxml

I am using OpenXML to manipulate Excel files.

I am sending the Excel files as memory stream, editing them and then send them back to browser so they open in client office program. I create new spread sheet by using this code:

```
public static void InsertWorksheet(string docName)
{

using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
{
    // Add a blank WorksheetPart.
    WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    Sheets sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
    string relationshipId = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart);

    // Get a unique ID for the new worksheet.
    uint sheetId = 1;
    if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
    {
        sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
    }

    // Give the new worksheet a name.
    string sheetName = "Sheet" + sheetId;

    // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
} 
}
```

My problem is that this sheet is added last among the sheets in the workbook. I want it to be sheet nr 1. I am looking for tips on how I can set my newly created sheet to be sheet nr. 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe instead of `sheets.Append` you call something that inserts it at the beginning? is there a `Insert` or `Prepend` method?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is. Thanks for the tips. This did the trick:
sheets.InsertAt(sheet, 0);